# After the Cylon Holocaust, how many people would know each other?

Tags: probability, graph-theory

If you are not familiar, in the show Battlestar Galactica (2003) the Twelve Colonies (planets) are wiped out by the Cylons which they created. Only about 50,000 humans survive in the form of a rag-tag fleet of civilian ships and one Battlestar (give or take).

There are at least a few instances in the show of people who were not on the same ship who are re-united or at least know each other from before the attack. Considering that -99.9998% of the human population was wiped out I feel like this would be unlikely, but I want to know exactly how unlikely.

Of course, I am not concerned with celebrities and notorious individuals who were "known" by a large number of people. I am interested in personal connections. Obviously the definition of "knowing" someone is fuzzy, but at least one study, cited in the New York Times, estimates that the Average American knows 600 people. In reality I suspect the real number could be significantly different, but this seems like a realistic ballpark number of people for which the average American could put a name to a face. I'd even be willing to round it up to a generous 1000 personal connections. American society seems like a good proxy for the societies of the Twelve Colonies.

According to Wikipedia, there were about 28 billion people alive before the Cylons attacked. So we have all the numbers we need: 28 billion to start with, culled down to 50,000. Average connections of, say, 1000, generously speaking.

To abstract and simplify the situation a little, why don't we just imagine that people everywhere died at random, ignoring the fact that survivors were clumped on ships. I am not interested in the intra-ship relationships anyway. I can calculate that the average person would know about 0.0018 people after the attack. What I don't know how to figure out is how many surviving connections between people there would be in a population of 50,000. And that is the real question. It's not just 0.0018 × 50,000, right?

I can't figure out the logic, but I don't expect this to be too hard for some math major to solve. Once you figure out the formula then we could see how likely it would be for you to know people in various social circles, like say 50 for close friends, family, and work colleagues.

Bonus question: would the fact that survivors were grouped into ships have a significant effect on the likelihood of *inter*ship connections?

Comment: "It's not just $0.0018 × 50,000$, right?" Almost ! If your previous calculation is correct, that would be $\frac{0.0018 × 50,000}{2}$, to avoid counting each connection twice (I know you and you know me)...

Comment: It would increase the likelihood that at least someone on the ship had a connection to someone on another ship. Think of it this way, if the survivors were only split between two ships, and there is a connection between two people, and each survivor has a 50% chance to be on either ship, then it's a 50% chance the survivors who know each other are on different ships.

Comment: @Evargalo, but, if there are 4 people in the world, and they each know three other people (everybody knows each other), and two people die, there is only 1 connection left. Originally the average person knew 3 people, but half the people died, so they should know half as many people, according to the logic I used, which would be 1.5, but in fact they only know one other person because there is only one other person left to know.

Comment: @ Moss: not quite, because you should count the average number of people survivors know, and you count the average number of survivors people who were originally there knew. Your reasonning becomes ok if you had the "I know myself" relationship...

Comment: I see. So what is the correct formula if we remove the knowing-oneself idea?

Comment: @jdods Wouldn't grouping everybody between two ships also have an effect of *reducing* the chance of intership connections, because half the population would be on the same ship as you and therefore not count?

Comment: @moss: each of the 2 people who will survive knew 3 other people. 2/3 of his acquaintances died, so after the tragedy each of the survivors will know $3-3*\frac{2}{3}=1$ person...

Comment: So the question is, given that everyone knows knows X people, and P percent die. How many relationships are lost? In the above example it was 2/3rds, which we can coun. But what's the formula?

Comment: Another scenario: suppose there are 100 people and each person is married to one other person, and half the population dies. I calculate there should only be a 25% chance that both partners would survive, meaning that there would only be 25 marriages left. If we just said that the number of relationships left = (ratioOfSurvivors × averageConnections × survivingPopulation)/2, the answer would be 12.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about it is to estimate the probability that two randomly selected individuals know one another. Ignoring all socially induced effects (you tend to meet your friends'friends, etc.), suppose this probability is $p$. Given that the pre-cylon population size is 28Bs, the expected number of people one would know is $28\, 10^9\times p$. I order for this to be, as you suggest, 600, you need 
$$
28\, 10^9\times p=600\rightarrow p=\frac3{140\,000\,000}.
$$
With a remaining population of $50\,000$, the number of possible pairs is $$
k=\frac{50000\times49999}{2}=1\,249\,975\,000
$$
All in all, the *expected* number of surviving connections would be
$$
1\,249\,975\,000\times p = 1\,249\,975\,000\times \frac3{140\,000\,000}\approx 26,78.
$$

Inter-ship? Well, suppose there are, say, 1000 people on each ship. Given 2 ships, $1000\times999/2$ pairs are possible, each with a probability $p$. Assuming independence, the probability of *no* inter-ship relation is
$$
(1-p)^{1000\times999/2}\approx 0,989354.
$$
Therefore the probability of someone on ship 1 knowing someone on ship 2 is $1-0,989354\approx 1.06~\%$.

Comment: Nice way to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I think you're working with the wrong constraints.

If there's 28 billion people over 12 planets, most of the population of each planet is irrelevant because they probably never leave their planet.

Even today, only about 4% of humans are travelling internationally by plane, and 1% of people account for half of all airplane emissions.
https://partner.sciencenorway.no/climate-change-global-warming-transport/1-of-people-cause-half-of-global-aviation-emissions-most-people-in-fact-never-fly/1773607

We don't have any evidence of how many people travel interplanetarily, but at a guess, at least half of that 50,000 are those 'super frequent' fliers, whether that's 1% or even less of the global population, same as today. This is reflected in the show by a disproportionate number of politicians and ppl in military, reporters, and finally people who work in space travel.

I'm not even breaking the numbers down here, but yeah, given those shared environments, they would be hugely likely to know each other.

Can't work out the proportions without estimates of interplanetary travellers in this universe.

1% of 28 billion is 280,000,000

Counterintuitively, the *less* people that were travelling in space when the cylons attacked, would actually indicate that it's even *more* likely that these people who survived, all associate or work in the same social circles, because that says most of the population never leave their planet, and these people are essentially super travellers, and super connected.

Comment: Yes, those are some good points. Now I would have to think about which kinds of people are reunited, but I think it was often the case that at least one person in the pair was not in the military, journalism, or travel sectors. I guess since this is a math site I was more interested in the necessary formula(s), and some simplification is necessary. But knowing a realistic answer is also nice.